# Shellscript - check a folder and delete files within that folder older than an hour

Tags: linux

How can I write a shell script that will delete files only from a folder that is older than 1 hour?

This is what I have so far:

```
find /path/to/folder -mtime +1 -exec rm {}\;
```

But this has 2 issues:
1. +1 is actually day not hour
2. when I run the script, I'm getting this error. find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

I plan to run that through cron and I'm testing it from mac terminal.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: You need a space between the {} and the \;

Answer (score 3):

Use `-mmin`instead of `-mtime`

I would rewrite it to:

```
find /folder -mmin +60 -delete
```

if your find does not support -delete use:

```
find /folder -mmin +60 -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
HOUR=`/bin/date +%k`

HOUR=`expr $HOUR - 01`

HOUR=`printf "%02d" $HOUR`

MIN=`/bin/date +%M`

DAY=`/bin/date +%Y%m%d`


touch -t $DAY$HOUR$MIN  /tmp/t.tmp

find /path/to/folder -type f ! -newer /tmp/t.tmp -exec ls -lt {} +
```

or

```
find /path/to/folder -type f ! -newer /tmp/t.tmp -exec ls -lt {} \;
```