# Nodejs child process for deleting 6 hours older files on a directory

Tags: node.js, process, exec, child-process, spawn

I am working on NodeJs Child process for deleting all files on a directory which are 6 hours older. I have already done : delete all files on a directory without directory delete. But can do whose files are 6 hours olders.

My code :

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var path = '../tmp/uploads';

exec('rm '+ path+"/*", function(err,stdout,stderr){     
  if(err)
     console.log('Directory Empty', err);
  else
     console.log("Files Deleted");
});
```

So I need help on deleting those files which are older then 6 hours

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using exec with linux command you can use

```
find /path/to/files* -mmin +360 -exec rm {} \;

exec('find /path/to/files* -mmin +360 -exec rm {} \;', function(err,stdout,stderr){     
 if(err)
 console.log('Directory Empty', err);
 else
 console.log("Files Deleted");
});
```

Otherwise you can use File System Package 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

Answer (score 0):

Use the fs package:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

You should be able to get a files age from that

You can use the fact package to delete files too instead of using child_process.

Here is a link to how to do it using exec and shell command:
[Shellscript - check a folder and delete files within that folder older than an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603655/shellscript-check-a-folder-and-delete-files-within-that-folder-older-than-an-h)

Comment: So that is not Nodejs functionality you are looking for but shell script instead

Comment: I have changed my answer with a link to another question on here with an answer that explains how to do it with a shell command

Comment: If you are using a shell command like 'rm' you have to use what the shell gives you to find out how old the files are. Maybe create a shell script you call from Node.js. But that said - why do you use Node.js then anyways?